# View direct references of class method when using interface in VS Code Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

While using "Find all references" feature in VSCode for methods of classes that implement an interface, I found that VSCode shows all references, including those of same method but from different classes. For example:

```js
interface Test {
  someMethod(a: number): void;
}

class Impl1 implements Test {
  someMethod(a: number) {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

class Impl2 implements Test {
  someMethod(a: number) {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

class Ref1 {
  constructor(
    private a: Impl1,
    private b: Impl2
  ) {}

 test() {
    this.a.someMethod(10);
    this.b.someMethod(10);
  }
}

class Ref2 {
  constructor(
    private a: Impl1,
    private b: Impl2
  ) {}

 test() {
    this.a.someMethod(10);
    this.b.someMethod(10);
  }
}
```

Clicking for example `Impl1.someMethod` shows all references to Test.someMethod.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to filter only lines that actually reference Impl1's implementation?